# Download file on unix from target url which autodownloads file on page visit

Tags: download, wget, curl, file-download

I'm trying to download a file to a unix machine on the command line. Accessing a GUI on this particular machine would be quite difficult. The file is autodownloaded when visiting the url in a web browser, however using wget or curl targetting the url with default settings simply returns the html code (as would be expected I suppose).

For example if you take a look at the links located at the bottom of the webpage linked below, the links labelled 'http' under 'download' are what I'm after. Is there a built in way within unix to do this?

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE32424

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use [lynx](http://lynx.browser.org/) or some other [text mode browser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_web_browser). You can just pass the url that you do know to it and it'll probably be able to get the file for you.

If you want a more streamline way to do this then you're going to need to get the [final request](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) made to the webserver for this file. If that request is different each time then a text mode browser is going to be your only option most likely.